# z-index positioning, making toolbar

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, z-index

I have question about proper positioning of one div over another in the following context:

I am making toolbar for `.col-9.h-100` from my snippet. I want it to appear over `.col-9.h-100` on mouse click. I know that it is not possible to make a child element of `.col-9.h-100` with `z-index` property higher than parent, that is why I am making a sibling element with the same dimensions and want it to appear on top of `.col-9.h-100` with `height` size about 20% of `.col-9.h-100`.

```js
$('.col-9.h-100').click(function(){
 
 $("\
   <div class='row' id='rowToolbar'>\
      <div class='col-9 h-100'>\
        <div id='toolbar'>\
          <button class='btn btn-primary controls'>addNode</button>\
        </div>\
      </div>\
    </div>\
  ").appendTo($('body'))
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.row{
  margin:0!important;
}

#rowToolbar{
}

.col-9.h-100{
  background-color:lightgray;
  padding:0;
}

.col-3.h-100{
  background-color:lightblue;
}

#toolbar{
  background-color:white;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
}

.controls{
  float:right!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded justify-content-between">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MAIN</a>
</div>

<div class="row h-100 w-100">
  <div class="col-9 h-100"></div>
  <div class="col-3 h-100"></div>
</div>
```

I tried many combinations with different `display` and `z-index` style options but none of them led me to the wanted result.

As u see when u run the snippet the toolbox appears with right sizing but in wrong place. What `z-index` and `display` "game" should I play to position them in the right order?

Could u please show me the right way for achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell toolbar in terms of what? And can you have any example link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your custom classes to the elements you are going to handle in javascript to avoid messing things up lately.
Also try to avoid creating html elements like this because it can have a good performance impact http://jsben.ch/zygb0

```js
$('.content').click(function(){
 $("\
   <div class='row'>\
        <div class='toolbar'>\
          <button class='btn btn-primary controls'>addNode</button>\
      </div>\
    </div>\
  ").appendTo($('.content'));
});
$('.content').on('click', '.controls.btn', function(){
  return false;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color:lightgray;
  padding:0;
}

.toolbar {
  margin: 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color:lightblue;
}

.controls{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded justify-content-between"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MAIN</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-100 w-100">
    <div class="content col-9 h-100"></div>
    <div class="sidebar col-3 h-100"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wait, this is not exactly what I wanted. Cause I want event listener fired on `.content` when I click on it and not when I click on button. That is why I wanted to do it with `z-index` routine. Could you try to make `.content` lie beneath `.toolbar`?

Comment: Updated. Notice that when you click the button the event bubble up and hit the upper element. You can add a `function` with `return false;` to stop it. Read more https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing 
Also notice that I use 'Delegated events' to watch for new elements and attach the click events. Read more https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: yeah, this works :) ty. But why do you avoid using `z-index`? Cause I thought it was the most natural thing to do?

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to handle styles with minor adjustments because it don't scale well. Try to stick to bootstrap classes as much as you can, or else you gonna lose your mind when things get big enough.